# Issue with mysql code showing wrong data

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I have an sql code that is supposed to show data old data but the issue is its showing data from after the unix timestamp.

This is my sql code:

```
SELECT p . * 
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN following f ON f.follower_id =1
AND p.post_user_id = f.user_id
WHERE post_user_id =1
OR f.user_id IS NOT NULL 
AND post_time < FROM_UNIXTIME( 1374634418 ) 
ORDER BY  `post_id` DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

This is the post_time that I am receiving:
[image: Post Times]

In reality it shouldn't be showing dates after 2013-07-24 02:53:38. The date in FROM_UNIXTIME is generated using the last value of the previous query with strtotime() in php.

Comment: Try using braces `()` to clearly mention items in your `where` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AND` binds harder than `OR`, so your WHERE condition turns into;

```
WHERE post_user_id =1
   OR (f.user_id IS NOT NULL AND post_time < FROM_UNIXTIME( 1374634418 ))
```

...which may very well return newer rows if post_user_id is 1.

You may want to add some parentheses;

```
WHERE (post_user_id =1 OR f.user_id IS NOT NULL)
  AND post_time < FROM_UNIXTIME( 1374634418 )
```

Comment: thanks the second one worked perfectly :D I can't believe I never thought of that

Answer (score 0):

there no issue with mysql..
its issue with the time stamp you provided

```
echo $time = date("Y/m/d h:i:s ",1374634418);
```

it returns

```
2013/07/23 10:53:38 PM
```